# How did they get $a^k$ from this?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logarithms

From Rosen's Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications, 3ed, chapter 8.3 p. 530:

[image: ak]

From the underlined info, this is what I believe they get:

$\ n^{log_b (a)}, n = b^{k} \Rightarrow n^{log_b (a)} = (b^{k})^{log_b (a)} = a^{k}$

Can someone explain to me the part where they end up with$\ a^{k}$ ?  This is a bit convoluted for me.  Thank you!

Comment: Is it clear to you that
$$
b^{\log_b a} = a \qquad \text{for} \quad a,b>0
$$? This is just how functions and their inverses work.

Comment: \begin{align}(b^k)^{\log_ba}=a^k&\impliedby\log_b\left[(b^k)^{\log_ba}\right]=\log_ba^k\\&\impliedby\log_ba\log_b(b^k)=k\log_ba\\&\impliedby\log_b(b^k)=k\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that $n=b^k$, for $b \in \mathbb{Z}$, $b > 1$, then we directly obtain that
$$
n^{\log _b(a)} = (b^k)^{\log _b (a)}.
$$
Now, since $\log _b (a^k) = k \cdot \log _b (a)$ (a property of logarithms), we have
$$
(b^k)^{\log _b (a)} = b^{\log _b (a^k)}.
$$
Finally, since $\log _b (x)$ is the inverse function of $b^x$, we have that
$$
b^{\log _b (a^k)} = a^k,
$$
provided that $a^k$ is positive (which it is).

Comment: Woah~  This is so easy to follow.  Thank you so much!!!